# visual studio gives and rise many issues and problems like

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

visual studio is not working it raises different issues like below:
1.directory not found,
2.Error or
3.IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
PS C:\Users\aryan\Desktop> & C:/Users/aryan/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/aryan/Desktop/file.py

Comment: C:/Users/aryan/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe  is your pyhon directory?

Comment: to be fair, python installs itself all over the place. On my system it has at least 5 install locations :(

Comment: To help you with this error `unindent does not match any outer indentation level` you'd have to paste your code by the way....